# puppet erb extra newline

Tags: puppet, erb

I have a puppet template that is adding an extra newline on each iteration of the inner loop.  The template is as follows:

```
;; THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY PUPPET
; <%= @comment %>

[production]
<%-
@data.sort.map do |provider,attributes|
    @data[provider].sort.map do |key,value| -%>
<%= provider %>.<%= key %> = "<%= value %>"
<%- end
end -%>
```

The output is something along the lines of:

```
;; THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY PUPPET
; Some random config file

[production]

provider1.a="1"

provider1.a="2"

provider1.a="3"

provider2.a="4"

provider2.a="5"

provider2.a="6"
```

As far as I can tell, that template should be suppressing the additional newlines.  Am I missing something?

Comment: surely it's just doing what you are telling it to?  There's a newline after the value and another before the end of the loop.  Just remove one

Comment: All of the loop is contained within <%- and -%> which should suppress the newlines though (at least that is my understanding). [docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html#tags)

Comment: I fail to reproduce. Your template produces neat lines for me. What is your version of `puppet` and `ruby`?

Comment: ...except the newlines are part of your data of course. E.g. `"\nprovider1"` and `"\nprovider2"` etc.

Answer (score 2):

try add '-' value in iteration. 
`"<%= value %>"` => `"<%= value -%>"`

**Change to**:

```
;; THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY PUPPET
; <%= @comment %>

[production]
<%-
@data.sort.map do |provider,attributes|
    @data[provider].sort.map do |key,value| -%>
<%= provider %>.<%= key %> = "<%= value -%>"
<%- end end -%>
```